# Установка пароля к базе postgres'а

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Подскажите, почему после установки пароля к базе, django проект все равно читает с нее данные? Вот моя последовательность действий:

```
sudo su
su postgres
psql
ALTER USER mydb WITH PASSWORD 'aequieF7yuy0ohGh';
```

В настройках базы в проекте такое:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'mydb',
        # 'PASSWORD': 'aequieF7yuy0ohGh'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы установить пароль пользователю:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql=# alter user <username> with encrypted password '<password>';
```

А теперь даем пользователю привилегии над базой:

```
psql=# grant all privileges on database <dbname> to <username>;
```